# Where can I find a decent place to do remote work in Addis Ababa?

Tags: internet, work, ethiopia, addis-ababa

I will be living in Addis Ababa from the end of February until the end of August. I normally work as a software developer in Sweden and I hope to continue doing that in Ethiopia (albeit remotely).

That means that I am looking for a decent place to work. A place where I can work like that preferrably includes the following, in descending order of priority:

  Reliable outlets

  Reliable and fast internet connection (I know this can be a bit shaky at times)

  Being able to work there for 8h a day

  Comfortable chairs

  An extra display (as I'm only bringing my laptop)

  Near the Old Airport area

An internet café might be an option, if they're okay with me working there every day of the week. If there's a place where you can rent office space (something like http://www.instantoffices.com/en/se/office-space/stockholm) that would be very interesting.

Comment: One trivial point Henric, don't forget monitors cost nothing these days. Just buy one and leave it in a local cafe!  :)

Comment: I can't vouch for Ethiopia but many places in Africa 3G is faster than the best available "regular" Wi-Fi, so if you struggle to find anywhere with good value Wi-Fi consider seeing if any of the networks do good value big multi-gigabyte data bundles

Comment: Regarding the vote to close: While I was not aware of Expatriates.SE, there is not a single question or tag regarding Addis Ababa or Ethiopia there at the moment. More importantly, my question would be very similar even if I was going to Addis Ababa for just a week. And as I see it, that would fit with the "working while on the go" which is included as on-topic for this site.

Comment: Relevant discussion on the Ethiopia Reddit: [Places to get work done in Addis?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ethiopia/comments/3mlv2e/places_to_get_work_done_in_addis/?st=j6sckd37&sh=d4843585)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for co-working space.

Google seems to returns one co-working space in Adis Ababa.

https://www.coworker.com/ethiopia/addis-ababa/iceaddis

There might be more spaces like that, but this one turns up on top.

Comment: Co-working space seems to be the term I was looking for, thank you! This looks great. I'll wait with accepting the answer until I've had a chance to visit, but this looks very promising.